# BigQuery - Transpose JSON data stored in repeated string field type to a table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following JSON data stored in repeated string field type.

```
"cart_items":["{\"item_id\":\"186\",\"item_name\":\"abc\"},"{\"item_id\":\"470\",\"item_name\":\"efg\"}]
```

I would like to extract each element to it's own column.
The requested result is a 2x2 table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the query I have written to extract the data from the string you have give to different columns.

```
WITH
  logs AS (
  SELECT
    '{"cart_items":[{"item_id": "186", "item_name": "abc"}, {"item_id": "470", "item_name": "efg"}]}' AS cart_items 
    )
    
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(unnested, '$.item_id') AS item_id,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(unnested, '$.item_name') AS item_name,
FROM
  logs,
  UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(cart_items,'$.cart_items')) AS unnested
```